# Is it possible to swap if the TransferFrom ERC20 function is unavailable?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, uniswap

I have in my wallet a certain ERC20 token.

However upon further examination I saw that the transferFrom function was a honeypot, meaning that only the owner's funds could be spent this way. Nobody else could.

I want to swap my tokens somehow since the liquidity is really high, but I cannot since the Uniswap uses transferFrom during my sell, which throws an exception. Is there a way to manually sell, or send to a certain contract in order to successfully perform a swap?

Can somebody please help me reverse the following transaction?

- https://etherscan.io/token/0xad8f026fe147a2ec9b0de06994aa747bd5326101 (honeypot scam token)

I guess this guy have a solution, but I don't know how to do it..
https://www.reddit.com/r/UniSwap/comments/j089lx/why_some_scam_tokens_on_uniswap_cant_be_sold/